# How to get unique Id for multiple duplicate properties

Tags: javascript

say we have a object:

```
   var db = [
        {Id: "201" , Player: "Jon",price: "3.99", loc: "NJ" },
        {Id: "202", Player: "Sam",price: "4.22", loc: "PA" },
        {Id: "203" ,Player: "Sam",price: "4.22", loc: "NY" },
        {Id: "204", Player: "Bill",price: "3.22", loc: "TX" },
        {Id: "205" ,Player: "Dave",price: "3.99", loc: "WA" },
        {Id: "206" ,Player: "Dave",price: "3.99", loc: "WI" },
];
```

202&203 and 205&206 have similar values for player and price but I need just one id for similar values i.e, output should be 202,205.

Can someone help me with that.

Comment: there is not code to help with so what you are trying to do and how is unclear, always show the code **you** have written. Also that is not an object it is an array of objects.

Comment: You have to compare those values, and if them are equal you should store it, and then when the others finished comparing, you return it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter it with a hash table for look up for the same player and price values.

```js
var db = [{ Id: "201", Player: "Jon", price: "3.99", loc: "NJ" }, { Id: "202", Player: "Sam", price: "4.22", loc: "PA" }, { Id: "203", Player: "Sam", price: "4.22", loc: "NY" }, { Id: "204", Player: "Bill", price: "3.22", loc: "TX" }, { Id: "205", Player: "Dave", price: "3.99", loc: "WA" }, { Id: "206", Player: "Dave", price: "3.99", loc: "WI" }],
    filtered = db.filter(function (a) {
        var key = a.Player + '|' + a.price;
        if (!this[key]) {
            this[key] = true;
            return true;
        }
    }, Object.create(null))

console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be a summarized answer:

```js
var db = [{ Id: "201", Player: "Jon", price: "3.99", loc: "NJ" }, { Id: "202", Player: "Sam", price: "4.22", loc: "PA" }, { Id: "203", Player: "Sam", price: "4.22", loc: "NY" }, { Id: "204", Player: "Bill", price: "3.22", loc: "TX" }, { Id: "205", Player: "Dave", price: "3.99", loc: "WA" }, { Id: "206", Player: "Dave", price: "3.99", loc: "WI" }];

var result = db.filter((v, k) =>
    (k = v.Player + v.price) in this ? false :(this[k] = true));

console.log(result);
```